# Currency Converter program IF/Else Statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a currency converter program on Python and I seem to have trouble on my IF/Else statement. I wrote "Do you want to convert?" as a question and if answer begins with "y" then the user will begin program. Same with if answer is "n" then the program will exit. But now i'm trying to write a statement where if any other letter is written else than "y" or "n" then a message saying invalid answer will come up. So far it looks like this:

```
answer=float(input('Do you want to convert?'))
if answer.lower().startswith("n"):
    print("Goodbye "+name)
    exit()
elif answer.lower().startswith("y") or ("Y"):
    Amount=int(input("Enter amount to convert:")) 
    currency_1=input("Currency you want to convert from:")
    currency_2=input("Currency you want to convert to:")
else:
    print('Sorry. Invalid answer. Please start again')
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the elif to:

```
elif answer.lower().startswith("y"):
```

Since the string is already changed to lower case, the `"Y"` comparison will never match.

Answer (score 1):

First, your question is going to cause an error because you are asking the user to input a string, and then trying to convert it to a float, which does not work. Line 1 should just be

> > > answer = input("Do you want to convert?")

Next, it may just be a formatting error in your question, but your if statement is not working because you need to indent the lines within the statement.

Answer (score 0):

use an infinite while loop:

```
while True:
   answer=str(input('Do you want to convert?'))
   if answer.lower()[0] == 'n':
       print("Goodbye "+name)
       exit()
   if answer.lower()[0] == 'y':
       break
   print('Invalid answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you convert your input `answer` to float and then treat is as a string?
Try this:

```
answer=str(input('Do you want to convert?'))
if answer.lower().startswith("n"):
    print("Goodbye "+name)
    exit()
elif answer.lower().startswith("y") or ("Y"):
    Amount=int(input("Enter amount to convert:")) 
    currency_1=str(input("Currency you want to convert from:"))
    currency_2=str(input("Currency you want to convert to:"))
else:
    print('Sorry. Invalid answer. Please start again')
```